# An alternative for the verb 'eradicate' in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, verbs, paraphrasing

In a podcast, the host used the expression 'to eradicate a pandemic' a lot. For instance he said 'Which disease was eradicated in 1977?'

When I was talking about this episode of the podcast, I tried to paraphrase 'to eradicate a pandemic'. There is no alternative for 'eradicate' in Cambridge Thesaurus online; however, Oxford Mini Thesaurus suggests 'eliminate'. I looked up examplary sentences with 'eliminate' on both OALD and Cambridge Dictionary online and I'm not sure whether I can use it instead of 'eradicate'. My questions are first is it correct to write 'to eliminate a pandemic' in the context given; second, are there any better alternatives to paraphrase?

Comment: A pandemic is an event. You can end a pandemic, but not eradicate one. You eradicate a disease, or a population, not an event.

Comment: @gotube Thank you! What do you think about this? They wrote 'to eradicate smallpox' and 'is it possible to eradicate covid19'? So I assume you underline that it is correct to write 'to eradicate covid19' but not correct to write 'to eliminate covid19 pandemic' which doesn't make sense to me.  https://www.forbes.com/sites/coronavirusfrontlines/2022/06/15/can-we-eradicate-covid-probably-not-an-infectious-disease-doctor-explains-the-challenges/?sh=3eed163c5455

Comment: Yes, those are fine.

Comment: _Eradicate_ literally means 'pull up by the roots'. You can eradicate a thing like a weed or a disease, but you can't eradicate a happening like a pandemic - only bring it to an end.

Comment: @orhantorun: "covid19 has been eradicated" means "we've reached a state where no one at all has covid19". But "the covid19 pandemic has ended" means "the spread of contamination of covid19 is no longer high enough for it to be considered a pandemic", which is a much weaker statement. If you mix the two and write "the covid19 pandemic has been eradicated", it just sounds like you're using random words with no precise meaning.

Comment: From [_Yes, Prime Minister_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0751840/): 
ᴅᴏʀᴏᴛʜʏ: Get rid of the Department Of Education. 
ᴊɪᴍ: I don't understand. 
ᴅᴏʀᴏᴛʜʏ: Get rid of it!  Abolish it!  Remove it!  Expunge it, eliminate it, eradicate it, _exterminate_ it!  Get rid of it!!! 
ᴊɪᴍ: …Get rid of it?? 
ᴅᴏʀᴏᴛʜʏ: Yes! 
ᴊɪᴍ: I couldn't do that… 
ᴅᴏʀᴏᴛʜʏ: Why not?  What does it _do_? 
ᴊɪᴍ: I _could_ do that…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Eliminate" would be possible, but not the best word.  The usual colocation is "eradicate a disease".

You can "eliminate" something by moving it, not destroying it.  It is used in contexts like "The police eliminated him from their inquiries."  (The didn't destroy him, just moved him out of the set of suspects)  (The etymology is Latin *ex limine* and notice the connection to the word "limits"

So the better word to is eradicate, which means destroy completely (The etymology gives "pull out by the roots, and notice the connection to the word "radish")

So, one "eradicates" a disease.  But "eradicate a pandemic" seems an odd choice of words.  Does it mean that the disease causing the pandemic has been eradicated, or the disease is no longer causing pandemic levels of infection? Neither "eliminate" nor "eradicate" seems to be the ideal word, and I'd suggest "control the pandemic" or (passively) "The pandemic passes".

Comment: @Stef  addressed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative.  That's the reason you didn't find one.

*Obliterate* or *annihilate* would work.  They mean almost the exact same thing as *eradicate* but only *eradicate* can be idiomatically applied to disease.

If you want to be adventurous and have your audience think, *Hmmm, that sounds odd but unique*, use *obliterate* or *annihilate*.  If you want to sound idiomatic and well spoken, use *eradicate*.

Comment: It appears that prior to 1900 people did sometimes write that disease was being *annihilated*.  Since then, almost nothing.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=annihilate+disease%2Cobliterate+disease%2Ceradicate+disease%2Celiminate+disease&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if you are asking for an alternative expression for eradicating a disease or an expression for ending a pandemic. These are entirely different things.

If you are talking about the latter, you can just use the perfectly good plain English verb **to end** a pandemic.

If you are talking about the former, you can say that the disease was **stamped out**.

Examples of usage:

"In the United States, examples include measles, rubella and diphtheria -- all of which were largely stamped out by vaccination." ([source](https://In%20the%20United%20States,%20examples%20include%20measles,%20rubella%20and%20diphtheria%20--%20all%20of%20which%20were%20largely%20stamped%20out%20by%20vaccination.))

"Researchers have successfully stamped out the fish disease VHS in Denmark." ([source](https://sciencenordic.com/agriculture-agriculture--fisheries-animals/dreaded-fish-disease-stamped-out-in-denmark/1463539))

"Smallpox has been stamped out and various other diseases are declining, thanks to vaccination." ([source](https://sangerinstitute.blog/2019/08/02/vaccines-life-savers-against-infectious-diseases/))